# VB.NET Math Operation (No Scientific Notation)

Tags: vb.net, math

Hello im having trouble with some addition in VB.NET, when i add 102030 with 97624362828262522215 i get a scientific notation like this (9.76243628282626E+19). How do i prevent the rounding and the scientific notation and just show the large number? Thanks.

My Code:

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    sum.Text = Val(message.Text) + Val(mykey.Text)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could print it using [`String.Format`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx) like so:

```
sum.Text = String.Format("{0:n0}", total)
```

As an example snippet in a Console Application

```
Imports System

Public Module Module1
    Public Sub Main()
        dim value1 as string = "102030"
        dim value2 as string = "97624362828262522215"
        dim total = Convert.ToDecimal(value1) + Convert.ToDecimal(value2)

        Console.WriteLine( "{0:n0}", total )
    End Sub
End Module
```

Which outputs

> 97,624,362,828,262,600,000

Also, [`Val`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7beh1x9(v=vs.90).aspx) is deprecated, if you are anyhow planning to change the code, you might as well use [`Convert.ToDecimal`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.todecimal(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`Decimal.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I did this under button click:                                                                                                                      
        Dim value1 As String = message.Text
        Dim value2 As String = mykey.Text
        Dim total = Convert.ToDouble(value1) + Convert.ToDouble(value2)
        String.Format("{0:n0}", total)
        sum.Text = total                                                                                          and i am still getting scientific notation

Comment: also tried: sum.Text = Convert.ToDouble(message.Text) + Convert.ToDouble(mykey.Text) and still didnt work

Comment: @alan7811 It should be `sum.Text = String.Format("{0:n0}", total)` as string.format returns a formatted text

Comment: ok, that solved the issue. But it seems like its still rounding the large number for ex. 456789854345678987654323456 + 102030 = 
456789854345678987654425486, but is showing: 456,789,854,345,679,000,000,000,000, do you know how to fix?

Comment: Oh sorry, that's because of it's precision, I updated the answer to use `ToDecimal` instead, which seems to fix the problem. However, if I may ask back, why in gods name do you need such large numbers?

Comment: alright that seems to have sloved everything thank you very much sir i appreciate it. Well if you must know, im creating my own RSA encryption and it requires very large numbers ;), go read up on it, its very fasinating. I guess math class did pay off afterall..

Comment: hey man it seems like there is a limit to how large the final answer can be and i need it to be longer. Up to 100-200 characters long, Any way to fix this?

Comment: @alan7811 Then probably you don't really need numbers, but rather a textual representation of a key for your solution. Cause you have to be honest, there is nothing that can be usefully expressed in a number that large that requires the precision you ask for (except maybe that you could put it in a different base, like 3.5 light year and stuff ;))